# dpkg: error processing package shim-signed

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dpkg

I'm getting this error after running `sudo apt-get upgrade` in ubuntu 22.04:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  iptables libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-gl-515 libxtables12
  linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515
  nvidia-kernel-source-515 nvidia-utils-515 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up shim-signed (1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but it returns the same error. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  doesn't help either. Can you think of anything that could reslove the issue?